Double tap and scroll within scrollable container without JQuery
I want to achieve double tap and scroll feature in my editor container, Currently I could able to scroll the contents inside it with scroll bar or double swipe. Here is simple representation of my code
HTML
<div class="outer">
  <div class="editor-container-outer" >
    <div class="editor-container" >
      My editor components
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

CSS:
.outer {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.editor-container-outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.editor-container {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 1500px;
  overflow: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

I don't want to use JQuery, and I am using Angular v17. Thanks In advance

<div class="outer">
  <div class="editor-container-outer" (touchstart)="handleTouchStart($event)" (touchend)="handleTouchEnd($event)">
    <div class="editor-container">
      My editor components
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.css']
})
export class YourComponent {
  @ViewChild('editorContainerOuter', { static: true }) editorContainerOuter: ElementRef;
  private lastTouchTime = 0;
  private touchTimeout: any;

  handleTouchStart(event: TouchEvent) {
    this.lastTouchTime = new Date().getTime();
  }

  handleTouchEnd(event: TouchEvent) {
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    const tapInterval = 250; // Adjust tap interval as needed (in milliseconds)

    clearTimeout(this.touchTimeout);

    if (currentTime - this.lastTouchTime <= tapInterval) {
      // Double tap detected!
      this.handleDoubleTap(event);
    } else {
      this.lastTouchTime = 0;
      this.touchTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        // Single tap handling (optional)
      }, tapInterval);
    }
  }

  handleDoubleTap(event: TouchEvent) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior (optional)
    this.editorContainerOuter.nativeElement.scrollTop += 100; // Adjust scroll amount as needed
  }
}

